# Python | addition of pattern 1 22 333 4444 55555​ ....?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sequence, addition

How do i do addition of 1 22 333 4444 55555​ ....?

i) case 1: n = 1, v = 1

ii) case 2: n= 2, v = 23 (Note: 23 is derived as 1 + 22)

```
def create_sequence():

   n = int(input('Enter the number till which you want the sequence:'))

   for i in range(1,n+1):

       print(str(i) * i)

   

create_sequence()
```

Comment: Convert the string to an integer and add it to the result variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generate a sequence of elements of the form `str(i)*i`, which you cast into an integer, then `sum` that sequence.

```py
def create_sequence(n):
    return sum(int(str(i)*i) for i in range(1, n+1))

create_sequence(int(input('Enter the number till which you want the sequence: ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of loops, they are your friend

```
def create_sequence():

   n = int(input('Enter the number till which you want the sequence:'))
   sum = 0
   for x in range(1, n+1):
       string = ""
       for i in range(1, x+1):
           string += str(x)
       sum += int(string)
   return sum
print(create_sequence())
```